# MongoClient throw MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I saw these posts on SO describing this error. Most of them was by the reason that JavaScript is async and mongoClient.close() called outside of callback. That's not my case, but I don't know what else can be the reason.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

module.exports = class Mongo {
    insertOne(article) {
        mongoClient.connect((err, client) => {
            const db = client.db('grabber');
            db.collection("zr").insertOne(article, (err, res) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                mongoClient.close();
            });
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I observed that you open `mongoClient.connect()` in the `insertOne()` method, and also call `mongoClient.close()` within that method, with `mongoClient` as a global variable.

My hunch is that either:

- There's another method that calls `mongoClient` that was closed by this method, or
- You called the `insertOne(article)` twice

I can confirm that the second reason is the most likely one. Here's the code I tried:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

class Mongo {
    insertOne(article) {
        mongoClient.connect((err, client) => {
            const db = client.db('grabber');
            db.collection("zr").insertOne(article, (err, res) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                mongoClient.close();
            });
        });
    };
};

x = new Mongo()
setTimeout(function() { x.insertOne({'a': 1}); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function() { x.insertOne({'a': 2}); }, 2000);
```

The two `setTimeout` was there to ensure that the two `insertOne()` are called one after another. Result:

```
MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
```

The way your code is currently structured, the node driver creates a new connection pool every time `insertOne()` is called. This is not optimal, and prevents the node driver to utilize connection pooling.

Instead of calling `mongoClient.connect()` inside `insertOne()`, call it globally outside of `class Mongo`. Pass the global connection object (the returned object from `mongoClient.connect()`) instead of the `mongoClient` object itself to your `insertOne()` method.